# Azure/Bing Image Search API: How do I add multiple image filters?

Tags: api, azure, bing

I'm trying to only return images that are Style:Photo **and** Aspect:Tall.

I can only seem to search for one ImageFilters parameter, like this:

```
https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Image?Query='Houses'&$format=JSON&ImageFilters='Style:Photo'&Market='en-us'
```

The important part:

```
&ImageFilters='Style:Photo'
```

If I try to add another one, like this:

```
ImageFilters='Style:Photo'+'Aspect:Tall'
```

I get this error:

```
Parameter: ImageFilters has an invalid pattern of characters
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried the following query with multiple Image Filter directly at Bing Search API Dataset which worked correctly with my subscription:

https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/Image?Query=%27justin%20biber%27&ImageFilters=%27Style%3aPhoto%2bSize%3aSmall%2bAspect%3aTall%27&$top=50&$format=Atom

equivalent to as below:

https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/Image?Query='justin biber'&ImageFilters='Style:Photo+Size:Small+Aspect:Tall'&$top=50&$format=Atom

So if you try putting whole ImageFilter into **one single quote** as **ImageFilters='Style:Photo+Size:Small+Aspect:Tall'** and it should work.

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work for me... very strange. I get the "Parameter: ImageFilters has an invalid pattern of characters" error.

Comment: I'm using it in iOS... I think it must be an issue with the + sign. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

if **ImageFilters='Style:Photo+Size:Small+Aspect:Tall'** not work then try to change **+** sign to **%2B**

```
ImageFilters='Style:Photo%2BSize:Small%2BAspect:Tall'
```

it work for me.

and if you use **BingSearchContainer.cs** there is one another problem you can't use + sign or %2B the solution is to replace

```
query = query.AddQueryOption("ImageFilters", string.Concat("\'", 
System.Uri.EscapeDataString(ImageFilters), 
"\'"));
```

with

```
query = query.AddQueryOption("ImageFilters", string.Concat("\'", 
ImageFilters, 
"\'"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is old, but I had a similar problem which I solved. One problem is that

```
ImageFilters='Style:Photo'+'Aspect:Tall'
```

should be `ImageFilters='Style:Photo+Aspect:Tall'`, so quoting the whole value, not the individual parameters. The other nonobvious thing here is replacement. This was successfully implemented in a python repo at https://github.com/xthepoet/pyBingSearchAPI. Part of the code:

```
request = string.replace(request, "'", '%27')
request = string.replace(request, '"', '%27')
request = string.replace(request, '+', '%2b')
request = string.replace(request, ' ', '%20')
request = string.replace(request, ':', '%3a')
```

This should give the idea!